# Highcharts heatmap without fixed non-temporal axis

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I wanna use the heatmap, but not with fixed categories.

All the examples (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/19/) I found had either only date axis or fixed categories, but I would like to have heatmap boxes on a chart with axis that have no predefined categories on the axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('customContainer', {
        title: {
            text: 'Wealth Development'
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: Date.UTC(2017,1,1),
            max: Date.UTC(2023,1,1),
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 8000,
            title: {
                text: 'Wealth'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'K';
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'heatmap',
                name: 'SAA heat',
                rowsize: 3600000 * 24 * 365,
                colsize: 1000,
                data: [
                    { x: Date.UTC(2017,1,1), y: 4000 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

The result should be a box with column size 1000 and row size 1 year. But it comes to a weird result with the exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Has anybody tried to generate such a heatmap? How yould I do that?

I would finally try to have something like the following:

[image]

The colors in the diagram should consist of many boxes, so that certain values could be displayed when hovering over a box area. So the colored areas would be like a lot of boxes in a grid. With the arearange that would not be possible to my understanding, because the low and high points are focussed on hover, but not the area.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Heatmaps are meant to be fixed-size grids of information. Your drawing looks like you may want some sort of column chart. Do you have some sample data to go along with your example that could help illustrate what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: thx for answering, I updated the question, I hope that helps.

Comment: Ah! What you want is an area chart with steps. I'll brew an example up for you.

Comment: yes, but the pink area should be able to divide in several 'area boxes' per column like setting cells in a grid, so that every cell could have additional information that appears on hover in a small popup.

Comment: Hmm ... in that case, perhaps a heatmap may be better ... with the cells you don't want defined blank or transparent. Do you have some sample data that I could plug in?

Comment: I think it's tricky :) as an example i tried to just set one cell of the heatmap, so all the rest remains transparent. But not with categories in the yAxis. So for example a box for 1 to 2 on y and 2020 to 2021 on x...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. The rowsize refers to the yxis-value, colsize to the xaxis-value, so I switched it:

https://jsfiddle.net/L7a9c0fr/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
    type: 'container',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 40
},


title: {
            text: 'Test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: Date.UTC(2017,1,1),
            max: Date.UTC(2023,1,1),
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 8000,
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'K';
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'heatmap',
                name: 'test area',
                rowsize: 1000,
                colsize: 3600000 * 24 * 365,
                data: [
                    { x: Date.UTC(2017,1,1), y: 4000, value: 3000 }
                ],
            }]

});
```

Comment: As for the circumfluent arearange, you can create border using line series (above the heatmap) and arearange as a body (beneath the heatmap series). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x1rv4v8d/.